# Using lambda if condition to column based on value of another column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Let's consider a dataframe like this:

```
(index)    condition    number
0          'increase'   1
1          'do-nothing' 1
```

I'd like to increment the elements in the `number` column if the `condition` element in the same row is equal to 'increase'. In principle, I thought about something similar:

```
# non-working example
df['number'] = df['number'].apply(lambda x: x+=1 if x['condition'] == 'increase' else x)
```

This example of course does not work. Is there an efficient method to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
df.loc[df['condition'] == 'increase', 'number'] += 1
```